# Area of a Circle using Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus

Someone showed me a derivation for the area of a circle today. They took a circle of radius $r$ and inscribed a regular polygon in the circle. If you take an $n$-sided polygon, then its area is:

$$\frac{1}{2}r^2\left(\sin{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\right)n$$

If you let $n$ go to infinity, then you get $\pi$$r^2$ as your area.

However, you are using the limit for $\sin x/x$ as $x$ goes to $0$ to derive this. In order to derive that limit, you need to show that $\sin x<x<\tan x$, which is done using the unit circle and comparing the areas of two triangles and a sector. To find the area of the sector, you need to know the area of a circle. Almost appropriately, we've reached a circular logic.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can use L'Hopital's rule to derive that limit, but that might be more machinery than you care for.

Comment: How about using the Maclaurin series of the sinc function to show that its limit at zero is one?

Comment: If I use L'Hoptial, then I am taking the derivative of sine. However, you need to know the value of the limit in order to find the derivative of sine.

Comment: If you define $\sin$ in terms of the usual series, then $\pi$ is defined as twice the first strictly positive zero. It is straightforward to establish the desired result from the series.

Comment: `To find the area of the sector, you need to know the area of a circle`. That is not necessarily true. One can compare those areas just by looking at the picture and not computing the actual value of the area of sector.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1